# Necessary and sufficient condition under which a Galois extension is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I want to know a necessary and sufficient condition under which a Galois extension $L$ over $K$ is cyclic. I mean the Galois group of $L$ over $K$ is cyclic.

Comment: I doubt that there is any really nice characterization, since these must encompass a huge, and widely varying, set of extensions. Is there any reason you believe there to be a nice description?

Comment: If this is homework or revision, please say so. It will help you if you show your working so far too :)

Comment: one of our professors said that this isnt difficult question and you can answer this question very easily, so I think there should be a condition, but I thought and even I researched about it and I couldnt find  any good result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple criterion which characterizes cyclic extensions. However, if the base field contains all $n$-th roots of unity (and $n$ is prime to the characteristic), then cyclic extensions of degree $n$ are all obtained by adjoining the $n$-th root of an appropriate element. This can be seen using [Kummer theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer_theory). In the equal characteristic case, one uses [Artin-Schreier theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin-Schreier_theory). However, when the base field is arbitray, there is no simple criterion.